# SetProperty allocating memory, causing Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, parse-platform

Is it expected that Parse (Unity SDK) will allocate memory every time you set a value? For example, the Parse example is:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore["score"] = 1337;
```

The following code allocates memory (1.3KB in the editor, slightly smaller on device, about 0.6KB.):

```
gameScore["score"] = 1337;
```

While the memory been allocated is small, setting values regularly (something that we do during our game) results in the garbage collector been called, which is causing noticeable spikes in frame rate. I've tried subclassing the ParseObject and setting values via SetProperty, but this is essentially what the above code is doing so the results are the same.

**Edit:** I am using the Unity Profiler to measure these values. Note the type of data does not appear to impact the amount of memory allocated.

I have set up an empty scene that has only one script which performs the following:

```
void Update () 
{
    gameScore["score"] = 1337;
}
```

This is the result of that operation in the Unity Editor. This happens every frame:

[image: Break down of setting value in ParseObject]

Comment: How did you measure this? Does every value take up this amount or just the first one?

Comment: I use the Unity Profiler to measure the data. Every value, regardless of value type, appears to take up this amount, it occurs every time you set a value, even if the new value is the same as the old value. I've updated the original question to show a screenshot from Unity profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `struct` rather than `class`. `class` gets memory allocation on the heap.

Comment: I'm not aware of using structs with Parse. Don't you have to use ParseObject to save data with Parse?